# Inserting values based on another column SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-insert

I've added the column DVDAtTime and I'm and trying to insert values using a subquery. Seems rather straight forward but I keep getting an error that I can't insert null into (I believe) an unrelated field in the table. Ultimately, DVDAtTime should be the number shown in MembershipType

My code is as follows:

```
Insert Into Membership(DVDAtTime)
Select LEFT(MembershipType,1)
FROM Membership
```

[image]

Comment: `INSERT` creates new rows. Because you specify only one column, those new rows have NULL for all the other columns. `UPDATE`, however, amends the contents of existing rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want to `update` each existing row, not `insert` new rows:

```
update membership
    set DVDAtTime = left(MembershipType, 1)
```